# How to input a sound via audio interface to RDP windows from macOS

Tags: windows, rdp

I want to input the audio interface sound to RDP.
My equipment starts at a local machine.

1. Host Machine: MacOS M1 Venture
2. Audio Interface: focusrite scarlett 2i2
3. RDP Connecting software: Microsoft Remote Desktop
4. Remote Machine: Windows server 2022 (AWS EC2)
5. DTM: Cakewalk

Anyone help me.